# attributes of a model

Tags: python, attributes

Can you kindly help me in the below query.
I have a Time series model - SARIMAX and have a model ( Refer below code )

```
mod = sm.tsa.statespace.SARIMAX(y,
                            order=(1, 1, 1),
                            seasonal_order=(1, 1, 1, 12),
                            enforce_stationarity=False,
                            enforce_invertibility=False)

results = mod.fit()
```

Now, i predict the forecast as

```
pred = results.get_prediction(start=pd.to_datetime('1998-01-01'), dynamic=False)
pred_ci = pred.conf_int()
```

So, pred is my object with forecasted values. I wanted to know all the available attributes of the object - "pred"
Like : pred.predicted_mean

Kindly help

Comment: I suggest reading the documentation of whatever module you're using.